# Using JQuery to get the values from the buttons in Div Table - made in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#table').click(function(){
    var value1 = "" ;
    value1 =  $(this).val();
    alert(value1);
});
```

I'm trying to get the value from any of the buttons to echo out in the jQuery function, but oddly nothing is working.

Here is the full file --> isn't very huge 
http://jsfiddle.net/yr2x7dnd/1/

Comment: Why did you include **3** versions of jQuery in your fiddle?

Comment: FYI, `value` is not valid attribute for DIV, you should use instead custom data-* attribute, e.g: `data-value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you fix the number of versions of jQuery you're loading, you then need to change your event handler to handle the elements you add dynamically.

Change:

```
$('#table').click(function(){
    var value1 = "" ;
    value1 =  $(this).val();
    alert(value1);
});
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click', '#table input',function () {
    var value1 = "";
    value1 = $(this).val();
    alert(value1);
});
```

You're also trying to get the value attribute of the div when you really want the input the user clicks on.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yr2x7dnd/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
value1 =  $(this).val();
```

to

```
value1 = $(this).attr("value");
```

Comment: I placed the <div id="table" value="hm"> to see if it even reaches the table but what i really want is the value of the button. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @Ace You should really improve your question then, because this wasn't what you were asking for...

Comment: @Ace In that case, see the answer by j08691